# Install4j shows wrong language at startup

Tags: install4j

i created an installer with install4j which has 8 languages. The default language is english. According to the manual of install4j the first screen will be displayed in the default system language. But at some systems i get the first "preparing the Install4j assisant..." screen with an different language.

At the logfile i get the informations :
user.language=en
[INFO] System language 'en'

There is also english as default language in the registry of the system (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Nls\Language).

Can someone help me with this issue. Why i get a different language at the first screen of the installation.

Answer (score 0):

The initial progress dialog is created by the native part of the installer, the installer wizard is created by the Java part of the installer. They have different ways of detecting the default language. You can get more information about the native part of the installer by starting the installer with the argument `/create-i4j-log`. A separate log file will then be created and shown in the explorer.

Comment: Which are the different ways of install4j to detect the languages? In the additional i4j_nlog_1.log i can only see one entry for the language (language/country is de_DE). This doesn't help me.

Comment: The language that is reported in the native log via `language/country is ...` is obtained via a call to `GetUserDefaultUILanguage`. It should match the default locale in Java.